# Why do two Deletes with different IDs but on same table cause a deadlock

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, deadlock

I am facing deadlocks in our SQL Server 2019 database originating from two delete statements. Our Isolation Level is READ_COMMITTED without READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT turned on.

My guess was that the deadlock occures because the IDs are so close and therefore reside in the same page. But according to the deadlock graph the two process IDs access different pages.

Why does this deadlock occure and how can I fix it?

An idea I had would be to force the system doing deletes to use the same connection/session for every delete, which would result in them being executed in sequence instead of concurrently. But that would increase our runtimes.

As requested, I share below the queries involved, the full table and index definitions, the deadlock XDL/XML graph as text, and please share the query plans via brentozar.com/pastetheplan.

For security reasons I have replaced the tables name with "Our_Table" and the name of the column filtered on with "Foreign_Key_Column". In the Create Table statement I replace column and key names in a similar fashion but try to maintain validity.

Beware: The server language is German.

First: The queries involved

```
Delete from Our_Table where Foreign_Key_Column = 78905 --Process 51
Delete from Our_Table where Foreign_Key_Column = 78906 --Process 68
```

Second: The full table and index definitions

```
USE [Our_Database]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Our_Table]    Script Date: 06.02.2024 16:17:28 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Our_Table](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Other_Foreign_Key_Column_1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Foreign_Key_Column] [int] NULL,
    [Other_Foreign_Key_Column_2] [int] NULL,
    [Column_1] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Column_2] [decimal](19, 3) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [Primary_Key_Name] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Our_Table]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Constraing_Name_1] FOREIGN KEY([Other_Foreign_Key_Column_1])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Other_Table_1] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Our_Table] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Constraing_Name_1]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Our_Table]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Constraing_Name_2] FOREIGN KEY([Other_Foreign_Key_Column_2])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Other_Table_2] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Our_Table] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Constraing_Name_2]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Our_Table]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Constraing_Name_3] FOREIGN KEY([Foreign_Key_Column])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Other_Table_3] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Our_Table] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Constraing_Name_3]
GO
```

First index:

```
USE [Our_Database]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [Index_Name_1]    Script Date: 06.02.2024 16:24:14 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Index_Name_1] ON [dbo].[Our_Table]
(
    [Foreign_Key_Column] ASC
)
INCLUDE([Id],[Other_Foreign_Key_Column_1],[Column_1],[Other_Foreign_Key_Column_2],[Column_2]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Second Index:

```
USE [Our_Database]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [Index_Name_2]    Script Date: 06.02.2024 16:27:00 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Index_Name_2] ON [dbo].[Our_Table]
(
    [Other_Foreign_Key_Column_1] ASC,
    [Foreign_Key_Column] ASC,
    [Column_1] ASC
)
INCLUDE([Id],[Other_Foreign_Key_Column_2],[Column_2]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Third: The deadlock XDL/XML graph as text

```
<deadlock>
  <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="process1eb2b5a3c28" />
  </victim-list>
  <process-list>
    <process id="process1eb2b5a3c28" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 8:1:12279678 " waittime="7830" ownerId="60983391" transactionname="DELETE" lasttranstarted="2023-11-30T18:20:47.690" XDES="0x1ebf3b43aa0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="6" kpid="8460" status="suspended" spid="51" sbid="0" ecid="4" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2023-11-30T18:20:47.680" lastbatchcompleted="2023-11-30T18:20:47.680" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.680" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="Our_Hostname" hostpid="8724" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="60983391" currentdb="8" currentdbname="Our_Database" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtend="152" sqlhandle="0x02000000cff49033589c5bbc920f9e3e6c20dd52ec7b2a6b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtend="152" sqlhandle="0x0200000054ea521e213370ce6f8ed8419b18c5e68fe33f980000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>  delete from Our_Table where Foreign_Key_Column = 78905   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process1eb2b5b3c28" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 8:1:12280105 " waittime="7827" ownerId="60983390" transactionname="DELETE" lasttranstarted="2023-11-30T18:20:47.690" XDES="0x1eb3c43cd70" lockMode="U" schedulerid="8" kpid="11956" status="suspended" spid="68" sbid="0" ecid="6" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2023-11-30T18:20:47.680" lastbatchcompleted="2023-11-30T18:20:47.680" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.680" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="Our_Hostname" hostpid="8724" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="60983390" currentdb="8" currentdbname="Our_Database" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtend="152" sqlhandle="0x02000000cff49033589c5bbc920f9e3e6c20dd52ec7b2a6b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtend="152" sqlhandle="0x02000000ac70fc271ab95a0c0039641710cac984cc29aae00000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>  delete from Our_Table where Foreign_Key_Column = 78906   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process1eb2b5c3c28" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 8:1:12280105 " waittime="7817" ownerId="60983390" transactionname="DELETE" lasttranstarted="2023-11-30T18:20:47.690" XDES="0x1f1c449d050" lockMode="U" schedulerid="10" kpid="2404" status="suspended" spid="68" sbid="0" ecid="4" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2023-11-30T18:20:47.680" lastbatchcompleted="2023-11-30T18:20:47.680" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.680" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="Our_Hostname" hostpid="8724" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="60983390" currentdb="8" currentdbname="Our_Database" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtend="152" sqlhandle="0x02000000cff49033589c5bbc920f9e3e6c20dd52ec7b2a6b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtend="152" sqlhandle="0x02000000ac70fc271ab95a0c0039641710cac984cc29aae00000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>  delete from Our_Table where Foreign_Key_Column = 78906   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process1eb2b051848" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 8:1:12279678 " waittime="7815" ownerId="60983391" transactionname="DELETE" lasttranstarted="2023-11-30T18:20:47.690" XDES="0x1eb3c87baa0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="1" kpid="2576" status="suspended" spid="51" sbid="0" ecid="2" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2023-11-30T18:20:47.680" lastbatchcompleted="2023-11-30T18:20:47.680" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.680" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="Our_Hostname" hostpid="8724" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="60983391" currentdb="8" currentdbname="Our_Database" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtend="152" sqlhandle="0x02000000cff49033589c5bbc920f9e3e6c20dd52ec7b2a6b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtend="152" sqlhandle="0x0200000054ea521e213370ce6f8ed8419b18c5e68fe33f980000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>  delete from Our_Table where Foreign_Key_Column = 78905   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process1edc2d288c8" taskpriority="0" logused="10000" waittime="2963" schedulerid="4" kpid="11376" status="suspended" spid="51" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2023-11-30T18:20:47.680" lastbatchcompleted="2023-11-30T18:20:47.680" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.680" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="Our_Hostname" hostpid="8724" loginname="Console" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="60983391" currentdb="8" currentdbname="Our_Database" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtend="152" sqlhandle="0x02000000cff49033589c5bbc920f9e3e6c20dd52ec7b2a6b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtend="152" sqlhandle="0x0200000054ea521e213370ce6f8ed8419b18c5e68fe33f980000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>  delete from Our_Table where Foreign_Key_Column = 78905   </inputbuf>
    </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="12279678" dbid="8" subresource="FULL" objectname="Our_Database.dbo.Our_Table" id="lock1ecc8c77a80" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057661130997760">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process1eb2b5c3c28" mode="U" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process1eb2b5a3c28" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="12280105" dbid="8" subresource="FULL" objectname="Our_Database.dbo.Our_Table" id="lock1ecc8d4f800" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057661130997760">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process1edc2d288c8" mode="U" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process1eb2b5b3c28" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="12280105" dbid="8" subresource="FULL" objectname="Our_Database.dbo.Our_Table" id="lock1ecc8d4f800" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057661130997760">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process1eb2b5b3c28" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process1eb2b5c3c28" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="12279678" dbid="8" subresource="FULL" objectname="Our_Database.dbo.Our_Table" id="lock1ecc8c77a80" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057661130997760">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process1eb2b5a3c28" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process1eb2b051848" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
    <exchangeEvent id="Pipe1ebc82f6380" WaitType="e_waitPipeGetRow" waiterType="Coordinator" nodeId="7" tid="0" ownerActivity="sentData" waiterActivity="needMoreData" merging="false" spilling="false" waitingToClose="false">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process1eb2b051848" />
        <owner id="process1eb2b5a3c28" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process1edc2d288c8" />
      </waiter-list>
    </exchangeEvent>
  </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Fourth: The query plans

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkiqrCJoT

Comment: Ok, give me a bit of time and I will provide the details 

Comment: Deadlocks with concurrent deletes is often due to a suboptimal plans, scanning more rows than just those to be deleted. I don't see the plans in your question but check for full scans.

Comment: Why is the query running in parallel and taking page locks rather than row locks? Is this from a scan?  Does the delete affect many rows?

Comment: @Charlieface I have now added all the details you wanted. I had to change the names of the objects but I have taken care to maintain consistency. Across all XML files and code blocks what has the same name in our DB also has the same name here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: That execution plan you posted doesn't look like the right one. The deadlock graph shows that the sessions are running in parallel

Comment: @MartinSmith I just ran the query again and copied that execution plan. How can I get historic execution plans?

Comment: @MartinSmith Why is the query running in parallel: I guess two users started the queries at the same time. Users in this case is an automated system. Why are there page locks instead of row locks: I thought that is default behavior for SQL server. Isn't it? Is this from a scan? I don't know, how do I check this? Does the delete affect many rows? Yes, one ID can have 100 thousands of rows.

Comment: A parallel execution plan means a single execution is running multiple threads. Your deadlock graph shows multiple process ids for the same spid and also an `exchangeEvent` so this is a parallel plan. In the execution plan you posted the table cardinality of `Other_Table_4` is `0`. Was this from a test system not representative of the system where you are seeing the problem?

Comment: @MartinSmith I just entered the DB and copied in the SQL statement from the Deadlock graph. If you say a single execution is running multiple threads then probably I did something different from our program that fires the SQL statements. I havn't acutally checked the code which generates the SQL statements and how that code connects to the DB.

Comment: Does this return any thing? (using the sql handles from the deadlock graph) `SELECT *
 FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats
 WHERE sql_handle IN (0x02000000cff49033589c5bbc920f9e3e6c20dd52ec7b2a6b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000,0x0200000054ea521e213370ce6f8ed8419b18c5e68fe33f980000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 0x02000000ac70fc271ab95a0c0039641710cac984cc29aae00000000000000000000000000000000000000000)`

Comment: If it does you can try plugging the `plan_handle`s into a SELECT from `sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle)` to get the execution plan

Comment: @MartinSmith when I run the query I get no result. There is no creation time before January. I guess we don't keep enough history to include those SQL handles.

Comment: Do you have QueryStore enabled? If you do you should be able to see the errored requests (due to deadlock) and the execution plan that was in use through there. Though if `Other_Table_4` did previously have a large number of rows and now has zero that could explain the parallel vs serial difference. Though still doesn't explain why the deadlock graph isn't showing page locks on `Other_Table_4`

Comment: @MartinSmith Query store is turned off for the database in question. I will check whether we can afford to turn it on. Need to do some reading of documentation first.

Comment: This won't help with your historic issue but if you are still seeing this type of thing regularly then it will be invaluable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues here:

Firstly, `Other_Table_4` has a foreign key on `Our_Table`. So whenever a `DELETE` happens on `Our_Table`, the server needs to check that there are no relevant rows in `Other_Table_4`, otherwise it needs to fail the delete.

But the problem here is that `Other_Table_4` doesn't have the correct index, so it's doing a huge scan on `Other_Table_4` to find the rows. This then deadlocks against other queries doing the same thing.

If you have a foreign key on a table then **that column in the child table *must* have an index**, otherwise you end up with a giant table scan to look for those rows.

```sql
CREATE INDEX FKOur_Table ON Other_Table_4 (FKOur_Table)
```

You can add other columns to the key or as an `INCLUDE`, but that column *must* be the leading key column.

The deadlock should now be avoided, because they will be locking different keys in the index, plus the query will complete faster and be less likely to deadlock.

---

Secondly, if the main delete on `Our_Table` is affecting a very large number of rows then you may want to force an upgrade to a table lock. Use `WITH (TABLOCK)` to do that.

This does have the downside of preventing concurrency, but if the rows are out of order compared to the clustered index (which they will be because it uses a different index) there is not much else you can do.

Comment: "huge scan" is a scan on a zero row table according to the execution plan posted. Also `Other_Table_4` doesn't feature in the deadlock graph - only `Our_Table` does. But maybe this is all from bad manual obfuscation

Comment: True that's what I suspect. Something doesn't match up because the deadlock graph is parallel as you say, and there is little chance the query pan as shown would have gone parallel. The point stands: in 90% of `DELETE` deadlock I've seen, it's down to a badly indexed FK.

Comment: @MartinSmith the zero row table might be in the execution plan because I repeated the exact same delete. And since the ID was deleted previously there was nothing to delete. I will check your method with the SQL handles on younger cases and might be able to provide execution plans.

Comment: @MartinSmith Even for yesterday's Delete statements there are no plans stored. At least according to the following query I built. We'll have to do changes to logging before we can get those query plans. 

SELECT t3.*  
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats as t1
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(t1.sql_handle) as t2
cross apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan(t1.plan_handle) as t3
where t1.creation_time > cast('06.02.2024' as datetime)
and t2.text like 'delete%'
order by creation_time